# The 'DelegatingHandler' list is invalid because the property 'InnerHandler' of 'handler' is not null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a custom message handler that I add globally as follows:

```
public class CustomerHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public CustomHandler(HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration)
    {
        InnerHandler = new HttpControllerDispatcher(httpConfiguration); 
    }
}

config.MessageHandlers.Add(new CustomHandler(config));
```

However, I get the following error:

> The 'DelegatingHandler' list is invalid because the property 'InnerHandler' of 'CustomHandler' is not null.
>   Parametername: handlers

So I changed the code to:

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new CustomHandler(config) { InnerHandler = null });
```

And I get an error:

> ArgumentNullException

When I add the handler to the individual routing, it works fine.

```
var customHandler = new CustomHandler(config);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "default",
  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
  defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
  constraints: new { id = @"^[0-9]+$" },
  handler: customHandler
);
```

So it always throws an exception when the `Innerhandler` is set correctly or null.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

This custom handler is used to check that a particular header is in the request and if found, gets the user details from a memory cache. Would it make more sense to change from a handler to a module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should read up on [HTTP Message Handlers in ASP.NET Web API](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers) to get a better understanding of the handlers.

> Message handlers are called in the same order that they appear in
>   **MessageHandlers** collection. Because they are nested, the response
>   message travels in the other direction. That is, the last handler is
>   the first to get the response message.
>
> Notice that you don't need to set the inner handlers; the Web API
>   framework automatically connects the message handlers.

If intending to add the handler to the pipeline then you should not set the inner handler. the framework will do that based on the order the delegating handler was added to the pipeline.

When adding the handler to the route directly there is no need for the inner handler so that is why it works as you stated in the OP.

Comment: Apart from WebAPI, I'm extend the `HttpClient` and I got this error... I mean, when should one actually set the innerHandler then? Why does this ctor exists?

Answer (score 4):

I got this error when reusing the same `DelegatingHandler` instance in several `HttpClientFactory.Create` calls.

```cs
var loggingClient = HttpClientFactory.Create(loggingHandler);
var authHandler = new AuthenticatingHandler(loggingClient);

var client = HttpClientFactory.Create(authHandler, loggingHandler);
```

The first call to `HttpClientFactory.Create` sets the `InnerHandler` property on the `loggingHandler` instance. Then the second call throws this error.

The solution was to use a new instance of the same type of handler

```cs
var loggingClient = HttpClientFactory.Create(new LoggingHandler());
var authHandler = new AuthenticatingHandler(loggingClient);

var client = HttpClientFactory.Create(authHandler, new LoggingHandler());
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got that error message because my `RegisterGlobalFilters` method below was being called more than once, caused by a configuration mistake, so the handler was being added twice to `MessageHandlers`. Just make sure you add it only once.

```
using System.Web.Http;
...
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration)
{
    httpConfiguration.MessageHandlers.Add(new MyDelegatingHandler());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Usually this error happens when you reuse the same "Handler" instance in a batch or a loop.

Disposing the HttpClient properly at the end of each request makes sure you always start fresh:

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient(
                HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline(
                new HttpClientHandler
                {
                    CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
                    UseCookies = true
                },
                new DelegatingHandler[] { new CustomHandler() })))
        {

            var content = new StringContent(request, Encoding.UTF8,"text/xml");

            using (var response = await client.PostAsync(requestUrl, content))
            {
                // DO response processing
            }
        }
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: It is not recommended to dispose of the HttpClient. 

"As a first issue, while this class is disposable, using it with the using statement is not the best choice because even when you dispose HttpClient object, the underlying socket is not immediately released and can cause a serious issue named ‘sockets exhaustion’." ... "Therefore, HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and reused throughout the life of an application."

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

Comment: DO NOT Dispose of HttpClients. The HttpClientFactory manages the lifetimes.