# HttpClient with multiple proxies

Tags: asp.net-core, proxy, .net-core, .net-core-2.1

How can one use `HttpClient` with a pipeline of multiple proxies?

A single proxy can be handled via `HttpClientHandler`:

```
HttpClient client1 = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            Proxy = new WebProxy()
            {
                Address = new Uri($"http://{proxyIp}:{proxyPort}"),
                BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false
            }
        });
```

I want the requests to pass through multiple proxies.

I already tried subclassing `DelegatingHandler` like this:

```
public class ProxyDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public ProxyDelegatingHandler(string proxyIp, int proxyPort):
        base(new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            Proxy = new WebProxy()
            {
                Address = new Uri($"http://{proxyIp}:{proxyPort}"),
                BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false
            }
        })
    {        

    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {                            
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

And passing the list to factory, but it throws an exception which is probably caused by incorrect implementation of `ProxyDelegatingHandler`:

```
    var handlers = new List<DelegatingHandler>();      
    handlers.Add(new ProxyDelegatingHandler(ip1, port2));
    handlers.Add(new ProxyDelegatingHandler(ip2, port2));
    HttpClient client = HttpClientFactory.Create(handlers.ToArray())
    HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);                        
    var res = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
```

Exception:

> The 'DelegatingHandler' list is invalid because the property 'InnerHandler' of 'CustomHandler' is not null. Parametername: handlers

Related Post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41889742)

Comment: What didn't work?  Were there errors?  Your code doesn't show how you are executing calls with the HttpClient instance.

Comment: @Brad, I added detailed exception. I doubt on the correct place of proxy usage, there should be some way to use proxy directly in the override of `SendAsync`